# Как сортировать ArrayList<DataModel>?

Tags: java, сортировка

```java
ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels;
dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
dataModels.add(new DataModel("0","f1","alttr"));
dataModels.add(new DataModel("1","f","allstr"));
dataModels.add(new DataModel("2","fg","alhstr"));
```

Comment: А что значит правильно? Какой вы хотите получить результат?

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`List.sort(Comparator<? super E>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-), передав ему цепочку компараторов, по каким полям, в каком порядке и в каком направлении сравнивать:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("0", "f1", "allstr"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("2", "fg", "alhstr"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("4", "fg", "alhstr"));
    dataModels.add(new DataModel("1", "f0", "allstr"));

    dataModels.sort(Comparator
            .comparing(DataModel::getField3, Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .thenComparing(DataModel::getField2)
            .thenComparing(DataModel::getField1));

    dataModels.forEach(System.out::println);
    // 1, f0, allstr
    // 0, f1, allstr
    // 2, fg, alhstr
    // 4, fg, alhstr
}
```

В классе `DataModel` должны присутствовать *геттеры* для соответствующих полей:

```java
public class DataModel {
    private final String field1;
    private final String field2;
    private final String field3;

    public DataModel(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    public String getField1() { return field1; }
    public String getField2() { return field2; }
    public String getField3() { return field3; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return field1 + ", " + field2 + ", " + field3;
    }
}
```

---

См. дополнительно:

- [Как сделать поиск элементов в массиве по частичному соответствию имени?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214586/419583)
- [Метод получения из текста частоты встречаемости слов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141130/419583)

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что вы имели ввиду именно это, но в данный момент вы сравниваете одно и то же поле одного и того же объекта, что является бессмысленным.

Для сортировки двух объектов по полю coeff вам необходимо:

```
Collections.sort(dataModels, new Comparator<DataModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(DataModel firstObject, DataModel secondObject) {
            return firstObject.getCoeff().compareTo(secondObject.getCoeff());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Извиняюсь неясно выразился в коде, исправил код выше попроще, мне надо просто отсортировать по первому полю, как это сделать

Comment: @JavaProgger В приведенном мной примере как раз отсортируется по вашему первому полю.